# Are there conventional synonyms used to replace keywords reserved in programming languages?

Tags: naming-conventions, computer-science, keyword, linguistics

The main examples of the words I mean are "object", "value" etc. In many (well, not really, but the chances are on some occasions at least) cases you may happen to find yourself willing to name a variable etc. of yours this way.

Another example I have stumbled upon in my practice is "try" which represents both the keyword (in many C-like and other languages) used in exception handling and the currency of Turkey. But this is an example just for fun, I doubt there are any common practices known for this particular case (though I feel like there may be for the previous).

What do people do in such cases? What are some synonyms for an object, a value etc reasonable in the programming and data modelling context?

For example imagine you are developing an object database, manipulating objects, properties and values (rather than documents, fields and... eh... values) is, for some reason, among the key ideas of its philosophy and you really don't want to use words too distinct from these semantically. What words would you use to replace the reserved ones while keeping the sense very close to that of theirs?

The easiest solution to come into my mind so far it to use misspelled (or spelled in a different language orthography) varieties of the same words like "objekt", "walue" etc. but although this  can do the job this just disgusts me so much I really don't want to accept going this way ever.

**UPDATE:** Indeed, in some specific cases (particular languages) using a different case (which, some times, may go against the case aspect of the commynity and/or the company naming convention by the way) and/or namespaces (which have been introduced almost exactly for this) may solve the problem at least partially but I am still interested in alternatives as I believe actually duplicating a system keyword is a thing one should at least think about avoiding (might there be a way to do it easily without accepting compromises considered too serious) in every case.

I am even considering writing script that would scrape through GitHub to analyse the common code elements naming vocabulary but I think it is always a good idea to ask first rather than to "reinvent a bicycle", perhaps somebody has done something like this already.

**UPDATE2:** *Please do me a favour and consider the following with applicable degree of objectivity before voting to close.* With all do respect I would like to emphasise that the actual degree of subjectivity of this question is excusably low (though, I admit, somewhat above zero anyway). The only real flaw of it is that it might perhaps fit [the English site](https://english.stackexchange.com/) better but I believe the audience of StackOverflow is much more relevant (generally informed in a much more relevant way) to the context. The actual goal of publishing this question is to highlight a problem that is fairly easy to understand clearly enough and which can not be denied of existence (though its importance may be questionable so far) but is spoken of too little (as importance of code clarity and semantic relevance is increasing, IMHO, code as a media is quickly moving towards obtaining bigger cultural (in the broad meaning of this word) importance than of books). And to let people share the ways of addressing it in practice they know of.

Comment: Can you be more specific and less opinionated? E.g. in some languages with case sensitive keywords, people use e.g. `object = new Object`. If you have a collection, use the plural. If you manipulate, add the verb as in `setObjects` or `set_objects` etc.

Comment: This question will undoubtedly be closed... but it's fun, so here's my commonly used list of Java keyword-avoiding names:

obj val cont priv pub dflt brk chr cls iface dbl flt imp inst lng fresh pkg prot impl ret thr trans

Comment: @le_m you hould not have deleted your answer as it IS a logically valid answer (although to a question some people may fail to see the rational, scientific part in). I would upvote it (and accept as THE answer if no more interesting one will emerge).

Comment: @Ivan A naming flow-chart based on your github experiment would be nice :)

Comment: This question would have been a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com, which is, incidentally, also a bit more tolerant to questions and answers of non-zero subjectivity.

Answer (score 2):

**Capitalization:** Often, a different capitalization instead of a synonym does the trick, as most language keywords are case-sensitive. E.g. `object = new Object();`

**Prefix / Postfix:** Another often encountered solution is to write `myObject = new Object()`. Which one you chose really depends on the naming conventions you follow. For private class fields, some developers use an underscore, e.g. `this._object` indicating a private access modifier.

**Specification:** In most cases however, you can find a more specific word describing the role - such as `instance`, `parent`, `child` or `argument` - or the subclass - such as `integer` or `n` instead of a generic number datatype - of your object.

In addition to the above, many language communities follow de-facto conventions such as `cls` for Class, `obj` for Object, `me` or `self` for this etc.

Answer (score 0):

The C# language has a built-in solution to this problem: The `@` sign can be used to prefix any identifier name, thus avoiding conflicts with keywords.

This is not really a solution as far as the C# programmer is concerned, because it is tantamount to using a different name; however:

This is a solution as far as interoperability with other languages is concerned, because identifiers prefixed with '@' in C# code are exposed to (are available to, usable by) other languages without the '@'.

This allows programmers of other languages to not have to worry whether the identifiers they choose might conflict with keywords of a language (C# in this case) whose syntax and reserved words they do not know and they do not care to know.